# Installing AssimpCy on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, fedora, glfw

I was following [this guide](http://morpheo.inrialpes.fr/~franco/3dgraphics/faq.html) but when I run the command:

```
pip3 install numpy Pillow PyOpenGL PyOpenGL-accelerate glfw
```

The command fails with an error:

> ```
> ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> ERROR: running egg_info
> creating pip-egg-info/AssimpCy.egg-info
> writing pip-egg-info/AssimpCy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/tmp/pip-install-ppb19bgv/AssimpCy/setup.py", line 88, in <module>
>     requires=['numpy']
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
>     return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
>     dist.run_commands()
>   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
>     self.run_command(cmd)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>     cmd_obj.run()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 289, in run
>     writer(self, ep.name, os.path.join(self.egg_info, ep.name))
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 621, in write_pkg_info
>     metadata.write_pkg_info(cmd.egg_info)
>   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 1117, in write_pkg_info
>     self.write_pkg_file(pkg_info)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 166, in write_pkg_file
>     long_desc = rfc822_escape(self.get_long_description())
>   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/util.py", line 464, in rfc822_escape
>     lines = header.split('\n')
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ppb19bgv/AssimpCy/

EDIT:
Everything is installed now, but when I run

```
>>> import glfw
```

I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glfw'
```

In my understanding glfw is installed.

Comment: Which Linux distribution?

Comment: Fedora 31 Workstation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install packages using the package manager, in your case:

```
sudo dnf install "glfw-*" python3-pyopengl
```

Then

```
python3 -m pip install assimpcy --user
```

In case you have issues with Python 3, you can also try with Python 2, like so:

```
sudo dnf install python-pyopengl
python -m pip install assimpcy --user
```

After that, use `python` (if it's bound to your Python 2 installation) and try again. But don't forget that [Python 2 is eol](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

Comment: This works but now I get an error, updating my question

Comment: You can try with python 2, updating my answer